# Why should I use erlang's gen_server:call in sychronize call?

Tags: erlang

I tuning the performance of my Erlang project. I am running into an odd scenario. Because I want to use the full power of the CPU power (multi-core) in some cases, the CPU usage will around 100% in my testing.

Then I found some strange things, there are some codes that must synchronized, so I use `gen_server:call` to do this task. But when the CPU is busy, the gen_server's actual task is doing with a very short time (read a value from ETS). But I finally got a long process time of `gen_server:call`. After my profiling, I found most time spent in `gen_server:call` is pending(90%+). In my case, the task run 3000 times. The total tasks time is about 100 ms. But the call to `gen_server:call` costs about 3 seconds.

In this case, why should I use `gen_server:call` if it is very expensive just so it can implement the gen_server behavior? It looks it would be better if I just do the task directly.

Does anyone have an idea as to why `gen_server:call` might be taking so long?

Thank you,

Eric

Comment: I am not sure if I follow your question correctly. Do you mean that the overhead from `gen_server:call/2,3` is what slows down your implementation? Do a lot of processes call into this gen_server, making it a bottleneck?

Comment: Actually I am not sure whether it's slow down by a lot of gen_server:call, but it  really has a lot of gen_server:call in my profiling result. I have a for each loop with 3000 items. At least three gen_servers handling these items at the same time. Currently I have removed the gen_server model in some parts of my codes.

Comment: Do you call `gen_server:call` in parallel? If so, the gen_server is obviously a bottleneck. You might want to move the actual computation into the clients to parallelize. If you do want to compute in parallel, I can write up an answer.

Comment: There might be several gen_server:call running parallel because I have some gen_server:cast task and there are gen_server:call inside it. But they should be different gen_server, I am not sure whether these gen_servers will block each other? By the way what you mean compute in parallel? It would be great you can give me some sample for reference. Thank you~~

Comment: Could you illustrate how the different processes interact currently, and which processes cast/call?

Comment: Finally, I try to work around this issue by spawn multiple processes to split my tasks (3000 items) into sub-tasks(100 items) and got a lot of improvement. My task items are independent to each other so I can do it well.  I may figure out that the process may not block by other gen_call finally. The blocking was caused by my serialized function call.  Each task need wait previous done. Even a gen_cast may cost only a little time, the task still got a little block if I have too many gen_cast inside a task.  Really thanks for your great help!!